# Creating in-memory raster layer using PyQGIS?

Tags: gdal, pyqgis, ogr

I have been researching quite a bit for creating in-memory raster layer using PyQGIS. i have done it through gdal "memory" layer. But i need QgsRasterLayer instance for displaying. I don't have the option of saving the results to disk and reading it again.
I tried doing this:

```
target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM').Create('ras', x_count, y_count, 1, gdal.GDT_Int32)

target_ds= processing.runalg("gdalogr:rasterize",
                      {"INPUT": ellipse_shp,
                       "FIELD": "id1",
                       "DIMENSIONS": 0,
                       "WIDTH": x_count,
                       "HEIGHT": y_count,
                       "RAST_EXT": "%f,%f,%f,%f" % (x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max),
                       "TFW": 1,
                       "RTYPE": 4,
                       "NO_DATA": 1,
                       "COMPRESS": 0,
                       "JPEGCOMPRESSION": 1,
                       "ZLEVEL": 1,
                       "PREDICTOR": 1,
                       "TILED": False,
                       "BIGTIFF": 2,
                       "EXTRA": '',
                       "OUTPUT": "aa"})
```

But when i wanted to use it as:

```
target_ds["OUTPUT"]
```

it gave me an error as

> TypeError: str cannot be converted to qgis._core.QgsRasterLayer in this context

Although [QGIS documentation](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsRasterLayer.html#details) says it supports all gdal sources, I couldn't make it work.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Perhaps, this answer could be useful: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218491/python-and-gdal-nonetype-error-while-reading-shapefile/218505#218505

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, I see that you have set the string `"aa"` as output. If you want to use your result for further steps, you have to set the last algorithm parameter as `None`.

Firstly, you need to change this:

```py
target_ds= processing.runalg("gdalogr:rasterize",
                      {"INPUT": ellipse_shp,
                       "FIELD": "id1",
                       "DIMENSIONS": 0,
                       "WIDTH": x_count,
                       "HEIGHT": y_count,
                       "RAST_EXT": "%f,%f,%f,%f" % (x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max),
                       "TFW": 1,
                       "RTYPE": 4,
                       "NO_DATA": 1,
                       "COMPRESS": 0,
                       "JPEGCOMPRESSION": 1,
                       "ZLEVEL": 1,
                       "PREDICTOR": 1,
                       "TILED": False,
                       "BIGTIFF": 2,
                       "EXTRA": '',
                       "OUTPUT": "aa"})
```

to this:

```py
target_ds= processing.runalg("gdalogr:rasterize",
                      {"INPUT": ellipse_shp,
                       "FIELD": "id1",
                       "DIMENSIONS": 0,
                       "WIDTH": x_count,
                       "HEIGHT": y_count,
                       "RAST_EXT": "%f,%f,%f,%f" % (x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max),
                       "TFW": 1,
                       "RTYPE": 4,
                       "NO_DATA": 1,
                       "COMPRESS": 0,
                       "JPEGCOMPRESSION": 1,
                       "ZLEVEL": 1,
                       "PREDICTOR": 1,
                       "TILED": False,
                       "BIGTIFF": 2,
                       "EXTRA": '',
                       "OUTPUT": None})
```

and then you may handle your result in this way:

```py
# You may use any name instead of 'result'
result = processing.getObject(target_ds["OUTPUT"])
```

Now it works?

Comment: Is `"OUTPUT": None` still supposed to work in QGIS 3.18? It tells me that it got a bad parameter value. And `processing.getObject` does not exist.