# Python and GDAL: NoneType error while reading shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile, gdal, gdal-rasterize

I am a newbie to `GDAL`. I have a shapefile of Britain which I want to rasterize. This file can be obtained from [here](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata) selecting `United Kingdom` as Country and `Administrative areas` as Subject.

[Following the GDAL tutorial](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#convert-vector-layer-to-array) ("Convert vector layer to array"), I have this script:

```
import pyproj
import osgeo
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal
import os 
import ogr, gdal
from gdalconst import *

#The dir and file to work with
mydir=r'C:\Users\GBR_adm'
os.chdir(mydir)
vector_fn = 'GBR_adm0.shp'

# Define pixel_size and NoData value of new raster
pixel_size = 25
NoData_value = 255

# Open the data source and read in the extent
source_ds = ogr.Open(vector_fn)
source_layer = source_ds.GetLayer()
source_srs = source_layer.GetSpatialRef()
x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = source_layer.GetExtent()

# Create the destination data source
x_res = int((x_max - x_min) / pixel_size)
y_res = int((y_max - y_min) / pixel_size)
target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM').Create('', x_res, y_res, gdal.GDT_Byte)
target_ds.SetGeoTransform((x_min, pixel_size, 0, y_max, 0, -pixel_size))
band = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
band.SetNoDataValue(NoData_value)

# Rasterize
gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], source_layer, burn_values=[1])

# Read as array
array = band.ReadAsArray()
print array
```

This script raises an error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'SetGeoTransform'`, and this relates to `type(target_ds)` being `NoneType`. I have read somewhere that this means that GDAL has failed to load the shapefile. **Why does this happen, and how to avoid it?**

Comment: You could try to open the shapefile via the driver function. You can use : ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile").Open(vector_fn)

Comment: Does not work. Returns `AttributeError: open`.

Comment: The problem is that the shapefile is long/lat projected and you are assigning a pixel_size = 25.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the shapefile is long/lat projected and you are assigning a pixel_size = 25. I tried your code (slightly modified for adapting to my system) by using (e.g.) a pixel_size = 0.0025 and, it ran without any errors.

```
import pyproj
import osgeo
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import ogr
import os 
from gdalconst import *

#The dir and file to work with
mydir=r'/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/GBR_adm'
os.chdir(mydir)
vector_fn = 'GBR_adm0.shp'

# Define pixel_size and NoData value of new raster
pixel_size = 0.0025
NoData_value = 255

# Open the data source and read in the extent
source_ds = ogr.Open(vector_fn)
source_layer = source_ds.GetLayer()
source_srs = source_layer.GetSpatialRef()
x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = source_layer.GetExtent()

# Create the destination data source
x_res = int((x_max - x_min) / pixel_size)
y_res = int((y_max - y_min) / pixel_size)
target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM').Create('', x_res, y_res, gdal.GDT_Byte)
target_ds.SetGeoTransform((x_min, pixel_size, 0, y_max, 0, -pixel_size))
band = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
band.SetNoDataValue(NoData_value)

# Rasterize
gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], source_layer, burn_values=[1])

source_ds = None

# Read as array
array = band.ReadAsArray()
print "min:", array.min(), "max;", array.max()
print "rows:", len(array), "columns:", len(array[0])
```

After running it, it can be observed at the Python Console of QGIS the min and max values and rows and columns of this array.

[image]

Comment: It worked! Can I visualize this raster from within Python itself, without any GIS software?

Comment: I think that the answer is not but, it is not very difficult to do a new raster with array values.