# pyQGIS: load an in-memory (MEM format) raster as layer

Tags: qgis, raster, in-memory

Say I have an in-memory raster (i.e. a raster made by the [MEM gdal driver](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_mem.html)), how can I load this raster into a QGIS layer? [QgsRasterLayer's constructor](http://qgis.org/api/1.8/classQgsRasterLayer.html#a6ce3b77f177e2d4e60ee2186aa0b8d0e) wants a path to the raster file, but the in-memory raster doesn't have one.

[Creating in-memory raster layer using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/218475/115) doesn't quite cover it as the solution seems to be to avoid creating your own MEM raster altogether.

If there is a way to load a numpy array as a QGIS raster layer, that would work too. I'm just trying to avoid having to write to the disk in case of a rapidly-changing raster.

Answer (score 2):

This has not been tested, but I would take the following approach: 
Instead of trying to load the data during the construction of the raster layer, load the data first into a Data Provider. This DataProvider can then be loaded into a raster layer.

The first step would be to create an empty QgsRasterDataProvider (i.e. don't provide any parameters). The documentation ([here](https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsRasterDataProvider.html)) shows a few potential methods to load the data afterwards:

- `write()`
- `create()` Look also at the [docs for DataType](https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQGis.html#acfb62493a1677c3498feec42ed0c50c3)
- `block()`

If this worked, you are now ready to create an empty QgsRasterLayer and call its `setDataProvider(provider)` function ([docs](https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsRasterLayer.html#a4617b774b5de99d050f6492fa39157da)).

I hope this proves useful. Good luck!